# Good resources for Graph labelling

Tags: graphs

I'm searching for good resources on different graph labelling, especially **Graceful**, **Antimagic** and **Antibandwidth Labelling**. Could anyone please help me with that? It will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will hardly find anything more comprehensive than the 400-page dynamic survey of Gallian [1] discussing almost 2300 references.

---

[1] [Gallian, Joseph A. "A dynamic survey of graph labeling." The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 16, no. 6 (2016): 1-219.](https://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds6/ds6v19-2016.pdf)

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer. I found that and that's a very good resource. But the thing is, I have a report due in two days on these three topics. Is there any way I can get a shortcut? (I know it's a 'sin', but I gotta find a way)

Comment: Never mind, I will go through the dynamic survey of Gallian. Thanks again Juho.